# Gas chamber problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure

Consider a rectangular isolated(non-conducting) chamber as shown below. The chamber is divided into three compartments. The wall separating A and B has negligible mass, no friction and is conducting, while the wall separating B and C has negligible mass and friction and is non-conducting.

Initially each compartment has the same amount of air at temperature $T$, volume $V$ and pressure $P$. Now compartment A is slowly heated through a heater such that the final volume of C becomes $\frac{4}{9}V$. Now my question is that once equilibrium is attained can I assume that each compartment would have the same pressure? According to the answer given in my book the final pressure in A and C are the same however in B has different pressure. Is this possible?
[image].